# Querying multiple SQL tables and returning the results from one or more tables in a single HTML page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to query several tables using PHP and SQL and return the format in a single HTML page.

Here's what I've got at the moment:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="searchForm" method="POST" action=""> <!-- My new PHP file would go here -->
  Search for: <input type="text" name="aSearch"> 
  <input type="submit" name="searchButton" value="Search">
</form>
```

**Controller 1 (PHP):**

```
// Connect to DB
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new MySQLi($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


// Collect Data phase:

// If an input has been given remove unnecessary characters
if(isset($_POST["aSearch"])) {
  $searchq = $_POST["aSearch"]; //searchq allows the input to search for part of a word

  $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq); //Can only search words

// Select statements if the searched word and insectName match
$sql = "SELECT * FROM insectt WHERE insectName LIKE '%$searchq%'";
}

// Tests if the code been inserted
if ($conn->query($sql)=== TRUE){
  echo "The rows you have searched for are:";
} else {
  echo "Connection failed: ";
  echo $conn->error;
}

// Show fields
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Output data of each row
if ($result-> num_rows> 0) {
  readfile("ViewReturn.html"); //Output it in an html file
  while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Insect Name: ".$row["insectName"]. "<br><br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

// Close connections
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
  echo "There was an error with MySQLi";
} else {
  echo "Closing Connections";
}

$conn-> close();
exit();
?>
```

**Controller 2 (PHP):**

```
// Connect to DB
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new MySQLi($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Collect Data phase:

// If an input has been given remove unnecessary characters
if(isset($_POST["aSearch"])) {
  $searchq = $_POST["aSearch"]; //searchq allows the input to search for part of a word
  $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq); //Can only search words

// Select statements if searched
$sql = "SELECT * FROM birdt WHERE birdName LIKE '%$searchq%'";
}

// Tests if the code been inserted
if ($conn->query($sql)=== TRUE){
  echo "The rows you have searched for are:";
} else {
  echo "Connection failed: ";
  echo $conn->error;
}

// Show fields
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Output data of each row
if ($result-> num_rows> 0) {
  readfile("ViewReturn.html"); //Output it in an html file
  while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Bird Name: ".$row["birdName"]. "<br><br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

// Close connections
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
  echo "There was an error with MySQLi";
} else {
  echo "Closing Connections";
}

$conn-> close();
exit();
?>
```

**SQL Tables:**

```
birdt:                    insectt:
╔════════╦═══════════╗    ╔══════════╦════════════╗ 
║ birdID ║  birdName ║    ║ insectID ║ insectName ║
╠════════╬═══════════╣    ╠══════════╬════════════╣
║   1    ║   Gull    ║    ║    1     ║   cricket  ║
║   2    ║   Hawk    ║    ║    2     ║   bee      ║
║   3    ║   Pigeon  ║    ║    3     ║   flea     ║
╚════════╩═══════════╝    ╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

At the moment I can search both tables separately by changing the action in my HTML form (which I can do from a dropdown) and return the queried results separately in different HTML pages but that's about it.

What I'd like to know is if there's a way to query both of the SQL tables from a single controller (and make that the new controller in my html form) which could query both of my tables and return the searched results in a single HTML page. So if I was to search a single keyword that matches either a record name in the bird or inset tables -or both- it would return it.

The thing that likely needs changing is my SQL query within my PHP file but I'm not sure of what to change it to.

I literally have no idea how to go about this and information online is quite confusing, so I'll accept any help.

Thanks in advance for any help. :¬)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM insectt, birdt WHERE insectName LIKE '%$searchq%'" AND birdName LIKE '%$searchq%'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use multiple query like that

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM birdt WHERE birdName LIKE '%$searchq%';";
$sql .= "SELECT * FROM insectt WHERE insectName LIKE '%$searchq%'";
```

and execute with `mysql_multi_query()`

for more visit : http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp